# adb shell wpa_cli set_network 0 ssid "ssid" command Fails

Tags: shell, android-wifi

I'm running a script to connect my amazon fire device with wifi but it actually fails exactly on setting up the ssid and password
script:

```
echo $DSN1

adb -s $DSN1 root
sleep 2
adb -s $DSN1 remount
sleep 2
adb -s $DSN1 shell wpa_cli list_n all
adb -s $DSN1 shell wpa_cli remove_n all
adb -s $DSN1 shell wpa_cli save_config
adb -s $DSN1 shell wpa_cli add_network 0
adb -s $DSN1 shell wpa_cli set_network 0 ssid "AA0RaI40RaI40RaI40RaI40RaI40RaI4"
adb -s $DSN1 shell wpa_cli set_network 0 psk "AA0RaI40RaI40RaI40RaI40RaI40RaI4"
adb -s $DSN1 shell wpa_cli set_network 0 scan_ssid 1
adb -s $DSN1 shell wpa_cli save_config
adb -s $DSN1 shell wpa_cli select_network 0
adb -s $DSN1 shell wpa_cli status
```

Output:

```
Using interface 'wlan0'
network id / ssid / bssid / flags
0       any [CURRENT]
Using interface 'wlan0'
OK
Using interface 'wlan0'
OK
Using interface 'wlan0'
0
Using interface 'wlan0'
FAIL
Using interface 'wlan0'
FAIL
Using interface 'wlan0'
OK
Using interface 'wlan0'
OK
Using interface 'wlan0'
OK
Using interface 'wlan0'
wpa_state=INACTIVE
```

can anyone sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
wpa_cli enable_network 0
```